# Attribute selectors with or without quotes?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Does it matter which way the following selector is written? It [validates both ways](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and the [W3C spec seems silent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) on the issue of quotation marks.

Option 1:

```css
input[type=text]
```

Option 2:

```css
input[type='text']
```

I've seen selectors that work both with and without quotes. Do both ways always work for either CSS or jQuery?

So, is using the quotation marks simply a matter of preference? Semantics? CSS version?

Do we have two methods because of *backward compatibility*? If so, which way is best going forward?

Despite [the accepted answer to this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113965/css-selector-for-form-input-text-fields), I'm thinking quotes is best:

```css
input[type='text']
```

Comment: In jQuery, the quotes are mandatory.

Comment: Is your question about jQuery or CSS or both? If it's a pure CSS question, given your concerns about validation where jQuery is completely irrelevant, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851091/do-values-in-css-attribute-selector-values-need-to-be-quoted

Comment: @BoltClock, I was really interested in both since they share many selector rules... although my description focused on CSS since I only assumed that's where the selector rules originated.  I'll also admit I never attempted to leave out the `' '` in my jQuery to see what happens.  **Thank-you** for the additional reading material.

Comment: I had a draft question-and-answer in Evernote about jQuery vs CSS selector differences... maybe I should go ahead and post it.

Comment: @BoltClock, Even if nobody else does, I'd certainly appreciate seeing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd sum it up this way:

- For some sequences of characters (legal identifiers), you don't need quotes.
- For all other sequences of characters (like anything that starts with a number), you must use quotes.
- If you KNOW what constitutes a [legal CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) and that's what you have, you can leave off the quotes.
- If you KNOW that what you have is not an identifier, you must put in the quotes.
- If you don't want to think about it and want to do it consistently all the time, use the quotes.

For `[type=text]`, you can leave off the quotes if you want to because `text` is a legal CSS identifier.

I personally prefer consistency and not having to think about it and less of a chance of making a mistake so I always put in the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

According to the CSS spec (versions [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) and [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)):

> Attribute values must be identifiers or strings.

Strings are double-quoted or single-quoted, `[type="text"]`, while identifiers, `[type=text]`, are defined this way:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Simply put, either way goes and it's a matter of preference.  The advantage of strings (i.e. quoting your attribute values) is for consistency; every value can be represented as a string, but not everything can be represented as an identifier.  You can run values through [this page](http://www.mothereffingunquotedattributes.com) to check on whether or not you *need* quotes.

Comment: Thank-you for the excellent answer but I cannot figure out how to use [that page](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes) you referenced.  No matter what I enter in the box, it assumes that it's meant for the `href` attribute.  I guess I wasn't expecting it to say `"text"` is invalid when it clearly passes CSS validation.

Comment: The site is expecting an unquoted attribute.  What you are entering is equivalent to `type="\"text"\"`.  It is just using href as an example - the value itself is what is being examined, not the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `input[type='text']` going forward.

Comment: Could you expand upon the reasons we have both methods and if there's anything conclusive in the W3 spec about this.  Thanks!

Comment: I just looked at the [CSS Level 3 for Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) and it appears you can use either.  I personally use the single quotes because all of the teams I've worked around do so.  I also use single quotes in my JavaScript.  The team does it uniformly for the sake of consistency.