# Hiding div with data-titles by CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a few divs on a website. Each of them has its own data-title. Can I use this CSS code? I guess I should do this by using:

```
 {display: none;}
```

However, I have a big problem with producing the correct selector.

Divs unfortunately do not have names, and class - and they can only be distinguished by the data-title. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target elements by its properties on css with the selector `element[property="value"]`, so:

```
div[data-title="something"] {
    display: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

About the comment's below on "use or not quotes" on css property selector, there was a question answered here on SO that covers the subject: [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Comment: @RaduAndrei Can you give more information about which browsers? A link would be nice. The spec says it's not needed if the attribute is a valid CSS identifier.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7286343/227299

Comment: Oddly, I've always had more problems with Chrome when I *do* quote the attribute-value (so now I use redundancies: `div[data-title=something], div[data-title="something"] {...}`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I meant. Let me still small, quick question. To hide I have a really large number of divs. Can I therefore build a common selector for several different divs, so as to simplify the code as possible?

Comment: You can select multiple elements separating them with a comma: `div[data-title="1"], div[data-title="2"], div[data-title="3"] { display: none; }`

Comment: Thank you, now I know everything