# Why does an attribute CSS selector work both with and without apostrophes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know CSS Selectors should be generally of the following format:

```
tagName[attributeName='attributeValue']
```

For example **Ask Question** button on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) main page is sitting inside a `div` element matching the following CSS selector `div[class='d-flex']`
However I see with my Chrome DevTools that `div[class=d-flex]` locator is matching this element as well and it is found to be a correct locator!
So, my question is why the CSS selector expressions without apostrophes around the attribute values are still found as correct by the DevTools?

Comment: apostrophes were never mandatory, they are optional. You need them for values that contain spaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do values in CSS attribute selector values need to be quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851091/do-values-in-css-attribute-selector-values-need-to-be-quoted) or better yet [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5578845/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#attribute-representation):

> Attribute values must be `<ident-token>`s or `<string-token>`s

You never need to use apostrophes. There are useful only for values with spaces.

```css
[data=ok] {
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
[data="ok ok"] {
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div data=ok>

</div>

<div data="ok ok">

</div>
```

Comment: I see, thank you!