# Is HTML Turing Complete?

Tags: html, turing-complete

After reading this question [Is CSS Turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2497146/1766230) -- which received a few thoughtful, succinct answers -- it made me wonder: **Is HTML Turing Complete?**

Although the short answer is a definitive Yes or No, please also provide a short description or counter-example to prove whether HTML is or is not [Turing Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (obviously it cannot be both). Information on other versions of HTML may be interesting, but the correct answer should answer this for [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Comment: Whether or not something is Turing Complete is *not* a debate, it's provable. To the people voting to close this as too broad: How is this question any less valid than http://stackoverflow.com/q/2497146/1766230 which garnered some wonderful answers that were hardly "too long for this format"? Ultimately the answer is a definitive Yes/No with some evidence -- perfect for StackOverflow IMO.

Comment: If it's possible to both "...provide an example illustrating how it is or is not Turing Complete." then it is debatable. If it isn't possible then your question makes no sense. Either way it should probably be closed as a duplicate of the question you referenced in your comment. You could always add an answer to that question if you feel things have changed since it was asked

Comment: I modified the text of the question to try to help, but the correct parsing of that English = "provide an example illustrating how it is Turing Complete, OR provide an example illustrating how it is not Turing Complete." If someone finds a way to both prove **and** disprove whether a language is Turing Complete, I will award them a medal.

Comment: Regarding the on hold status for "too broad": There is only one correct answer: Yes w/ proof or No w/ proof. There may be different proofs, but certainly not more variations of answers than a typical SO question. Good answers need not be long. The one answer so far is succinct, and there's no reason to believe answers will be too long.

Comment: The only comment from someone who voted to close showed a misunderstanding of the underlying question -- both "Turing Complete" (not something debatable) and "HTML" (as something distinct from CSS -- referenced in the so-called "duplicate question"). Please allow the community to learn from intelligent answers to thoughtful questions, and vote to reopen this question.

Comment: "please also provide a short proof or counter-example to prove whether HTML is or is not Turing Complete" is like asking "please provide a succinct proof of Fermat's last theorem." How does the OP know the required evidence can be short?

Comment: @holdenweb The responses to the similar question "Is CSS Turing Complete" were rather short. I suspect that the counter-examples to this question will be about the same size. Why does the asker of the question have the burden of proving that all answers will be short? Why not let the community provide some answers first? Then only if the answers become overly-long, flag the question?

Comment: Thank you for the question. I definitely would like to see it reopened. Jesus, SO community is often so deplorable. "Hurr, durr, what you are asking doesn't make any sense. I am so good, I know so much, I am part of elite, I reason only in formal logic, I don't use natural languages to communicate, I won't even mentioned what's wrong with the question in my perfect, enlightened opinion". Pathetic. Take this @JK. for example... Dear Lord...

Comment: The question is very objective, maybe "too broad" means "too deep for most programmers to understand, let's keep this shallow"?

Answer (score 44):

By itself (without CSS or JS), HTML (5 or otherwise) cannot possibly be Turing-complete because it is **not a machine**. Asking whether it is or not is essentially equivalent to asking whether an apple or an orange is Turing complete, or to take a more relevant example, a book.

HTML is not something that "runs". It is a representation. It is a format. It is an information encoding. Not being a machine, it cannot compute anything on its own, at the level of Turing completeness or any other level.

Comment: While I expect that "No" is correct, would you elaborate on why HTML is not formally a "machine", and why that's a requirement for Turing Completeness? Couldn't HTML be considered "run" when it is parsed by a browser, just as a JavaScript file is?

Comment: For starters, HTML hasn't any means of making a "decision", like `if ... then ... else`. It also has no loops, no variables etc. It is no programming language per se, it is only declarative.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can make html into a state machine where each state is represented by an iframe.

Comment: @TravisJ: how does that compute with "One of the key requirements is the scratchpad size be unbounded and that is possible to rewind to access prior writes to the scratchpad"? (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25213367/2564301) The same can be said from a plain text document in Notepad.

Comment: @Jongware - An iframe could reference a previous iframe thus making it a recursive loop. I am not stating that html is turing complete. I am merely saying you can create a state machine, albeit limited, with iframes that reference html which references iframes, and so on.

Comment: @TravisJ Sure, I can represent states with IFRAMEs or in many other ways. But to be a machine we have to be able to transition between states. How would that happen?

Comment: HTML5 with CSS3 is turing complete, as a Rule 110 implementation was written in it

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but isn't JS part of HTML with use of script elements?

Comment: @AnthonyYershov WWW consists of HTML, CSS, and JS (and a few others). Three separate specs that work together. Neither JS nor CSS are directly in the HTML specs, and are not required for HTML to work. The script tag itself only defines loading behavior/attributes, the actual implementation is elsewhere. A browser that supports only HTML but not CSS or JS is still in conformance with HTML specs (see Lynx text browser). As such, this answer is correct.

Comment: For those mentioning IFRAME's ability to access other frames, kindly note that this feature is not made possible by HTML but Javascript

Comment: @AnthonyYershov, the script tag is a good mention. But note that by definition, "A client-side script is a program that may accompany an HTML document or be embedded directly in it. The program executes on the client's machine when the document loads, or at some other time such as when a link is activated. HTML's support for scripts is independent of the scripting language." (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html). HTML script tag refers to an external script and not JS. Meaning, the script tag does not necessarily contain a Turing complete data.

Comment: I agree with Luke. HTML runs in browser. I disagree with frontend_dev.  A programming language does not need to have loop and variable. This is not necessary even for a turing complete language. In a broad sense, any config file, command line arguments can be considered a programming language.

Comment: HTML is not **designed** as something that "runs", but it doesn't mean that HTML is not. A lot of things are not designed as something that "runs": say, CSS or templates in C++. Nevertheless, there are ways to make them “run” and they are Turing complete.

Comment: A list or Turing quadruples on a page is not "machine" in the sense of your argument, it doesn't do anything but sit there on the page.  However, the language that the set of all Turing quadruples that form a valid Turing machine belong to, is obviously, by definition, Turing complete.  /The marks on the paper are written in this language/.   Likewise, a webpage is written in HTML.  "It is simply a representation of data" isn't any kind of valid argument against the thesis here; code is data is code.

Answer (score 24):

It seems clear to me that states and transitions can be represented in HTML with pages and hyperlinks, respectively. With this, one can implement [deterministic finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) where clicking links transitions between states. For example, I implemented a few simple DFA which are accessible [here](https://brunodantas.github.io/html-fda).

DFA are much simpler that the Turing Machine though. To implement something closer to a TM, an additional mechanism involving reading and writing to memory would be necessary, besides the basic states/transitions functionality. However, HTML does not seem to have this kind of feature. So I would say HTML is not Turing-complete, but is able to simulate DFA.

Edit1: I was reminded of the video [On The Turing Completeness of PowerPoint](https://youtu.be/uNjxe8ShM-8) when writing this answer.

Edit2: complementing this answer with the DFA definition and clarification.

Edit3: it might be worth mentioning that any machine in the real world is a finite-state machine due to reality's constraint of finite memory. So in a way, DFA can actually do anything that any real machine can do, as far as I know. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Comparison_with_real_machines

### Definition

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Formal_definition

> In the theory of computation, a branch of theoretical computer
> science, a deterministic finite automaton (DFA)—also known as
> deterministic finite acceptor (DFA), deterministic finite-state
> machine (DFSM), or deterministic finite-state automaton (DFSA)—is a
> finite-state machine that accepts or rejects a given string of
> symbols, by running through a state sequence uniquely determined by
> the string.
>
> A deterministic finite automaton M is a 5-tuple, (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F),
> consisting of
>
> - a finite set of states Q
> - a finite set of input symbols called the alphabet Σ
> - a transition function δ : Q × Σ → Q
> - an initial or start state q0
> - a set of accept states F
>
> The following example is of a DFA M, with a binary alphabet, which
> requires that the input contains an even number of 0s.
>
> M = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F) where
>
> - Q = {S1, S2}
> - Σ = {0, 1}
> - q0 = S1
> - F = {S1} and
> - δ is defined by the following state transition table:
>
> |  | 0 | 0 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | s1 | s2 | s1 |
> | s2 | s1 | s2 |
>
> State diagram for M:
>
> [image: The state diagram for M]
>
> The state S1 represents that there has been an even number of 0s in
> the input so far, while S2 signifies an odd number. A 1 in the input
> does not change the state of the automaton. When the input ends, the
> state will show whether the input contained an even number of 0s or
> not. If the input did contain an even number of 0s, M will finish in
> state S1, an accepting state, so the input string will be accepted.

### HTML implementation

The DFA M exemplified above plus a few of the most basic DFA were implemented in Markdown and converted/hosted as HTML pages by Github, accessible [here](https://brunodantas.github.io/html-fda/).

Following the definition of M, its HTML implementation is detailed as follows.

- The set of states Q contains the pages `s1.html` and `s2.html`, and also the acceptance page `acc.html` and the rejection page `rej.html`. These two additional states are a "user-friendly" way to communicate the acceptance of a word and don't affect the semantics of the DFA.
- The set of symbols Σ is defined as the symbols 0 and 1. The empty string symbol ε was also included to denote the end of the input, leading to either `acc.html` or `rej.html` state.
- The initial state q0 is `s1.html`.
- The set of accept states is {`acc.html`}.
- The set of transitions is defined by hyperlinks such that page `s1.html` contains a link with text "0" leading to `s2.html`, a link with text "1" leading to `s1.html`, and a link with text "ε" leading to `acc.html`. Each page is analogous according to the following transition table. Obs: `acc.html` and `rej.html` don't contain links.

|  | 0 | 1 | ε |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1.html | s2.html | s1.html | acc.html |
| s2.html | s1.html | s2.html | rej.html |

### Questions

- In what ways are those HTML pages "machines"? Don't these machines include the browser and the person who clicks the links? In what way does a link perform computation?

DFA is an abstract machine, i.e. a mathematical object. By the definition shown above, it is a tuple that defines transition rules between states according to a set of symbols. A real-world implementation of these rules (i.e. *who* keeps track of the current state, looks up the transition table and updates the current state accordingly) is then outside the scope of the definition. And for that matter, a Turing machine is a [similar tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) with a few more elements to it.

As described above, the HTML implementation represents the DFA M in full: every state and every transition is represented by a page and a link respectively. Browsers, clicks and CPUs are then irrelevant in the context of the DFA.

In other words, as written by @Not_Here in the comments:

> Rules don't innately implement themselves, they're just rules an
> implementation should follow. Consider it this way: Turing machines
> aren't actual machines, Turing didn't build machines. They're purely
> mathematical objects, they're tuples of sets (state, symbols) and a
> transition function between states. Turing machines are purely
> mathematical objects, they're sets of instructions for how to
> implement a computation, and so is this example in HTML.

The Wikipedia article on [abstract machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine):

> An abstract machine, also called an abstract computer, is a
> theoretical computer used for defining a model of computation.
> Abstraction of computing processes is used in both the computer
> science and computer engineering disciplines and usually assumes a
> discrete time paradigm.
>
> In the theory of computation, abstract machines are often used in
> thought experiments regarding computability or to analyze the
> complexity of algorithms (see computational complexity theory). A
> typical abstract machine consists of a definition in terms of input,
> output, and the set of allowable operations used to turn the former
> into the latter. The best-known example is the Turing machine.

Comment: "In computability theory, a system of data-manipulation rules is said to be Turing-complete or computationally universal if it can be used to simulate any Turing machine. This means that this system is able to recognize or decide other data-manipulation rule sets." - wiki definition. Your system would also include a human who would do the clicking, so it's not pure HTML. I'm pretty sure when people say that javascript is turing complete, they mean the engine and not the syntax.

Comment: @Anthony Yershov Computability theory is more abstract than that. You don't need an interpreter or even a CPU to determine the computational power of such a rule (e.g. a formal grammar). This kind of analysis is all about the syntax, not the implementation of the mechanism for transitioning between states. So I would say it's pure HTML as much as any formal grammar is "pure".

Comment: A link doesn't perform any logical calculation on its own, so I would argue that it couldn't be used to represent state transfer.

Comment: The hyperlinks not only represent states transitions, they also *work*. You can [test](https://brunodantas.github.io/html-fda) it yourself.

Comment: It seems to me that the DFA would be the browser, not HTML itself. The state representation is the URL for each page, not within its HTML. The HTML itself isn't even aware of its own state, but the browser is.

Comment: @sfdcfox Again, it's more abstract than that. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Example) simple tuple is a DFA, and that's what I implemented with the HTML pages above. The browser is just a mechanism to simulate it, and it's not part of the DFA. So the browser just happens to act it out, thus *behaving* like a DFA because it's following one.

Comment: I did read that to make sure I had the right idea. It still seems to me that each HTML page is a node, or state, within a collection of files laid out in a DFA, just like you can with, say, a [file system](https://github.com/8051Enthusiast/regex2fat/). In the example you linked, the 0/1 would be the href/link, the S1/S2 would be the pages. They are nodes within a larger system laid out as a DFA, but are not inherently a DFA in and of themselves, no more than any single cell in your body is "you." Anyways, was just my two cents. You've given me something to think about. Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyYershov In your quote "*a system of data-manipulation rules*" goes against what you are trying to argue. Rules don't innately implement themselves, they're just rules an implementation should follow. Consider it this way: Turing machines aren't actual machines, Turing didn't build machines. They're purely mathematical objects, they're tuples of sets (state, symbols) and a transition function between states. Turing machines are purely mathematical objects, they're sets of instructions for how to implement a computation, and so is this example in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

## with CSS - Yes...

Some have claimed to implement [Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110), a cellular automaton, using pure HTML and CSS (no JavaScript). You can see [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak_sWZyHi3E) here, or [browse the source](https://github.com/efoxepstein/stupid-machines) of one implementation (you can run it [here](http://eli.fox-epste.in/rule110-full.html)).

Why is this relevant? It [has been proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110#The_proof_of_universality) that Rule 110 is itself Turing complete, meaning that it can simulate any Turing machine. If we then implement Rule 110 using pure HTML, it follows that HTML can simulate any Turing machine via its simulation of that particular cellular automaton.

The critiques of this HTML "proof" focus on the fact that human input is required to drive the operation of the HTML machine. As seen in the video above, the human's input is constrained to a repeating pattern of Tab + Space (because the HTML machine consists of a series of checkboxes). Much as a Turing machine would require a clock signal and motive force to move its read/write head if it were to be implemented as a physical machine, the HTML machine needs energy input from the human -- but *no* information input, and crucially, no decision making.

In summary: HTML is probably Turing-complete, as proven by construction.

Comment: CSS does all the work though.

Comment: Fair point.

Still: all HTML documents can contain CSS without limitations; so, the problem of HTML Turing-completeness reduces to CSS Turing-completeness.

Comment: HTML documents can also contain JS though, which with that logic would make them turing-complete trivially